# Can I link an HTML page to my HTML page? (No iframes, HTML5)

Tags: html

I want to link header.html and footer.html to index.html and contactme.php so that they're both have the same header and footer. Is there a way to do this without iframes in HTML5?

Comment: First what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed HTML documents with the [`object` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element).

See the [example from the HTML5 (CR) spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element):

> In this example, an HTML page is embedded in another using the `object` element.
>
> ```
> <figure>
>  <object data="clock.html"></object>
>  <figcaption>My HTML Clock</figcaption>
> </figure>
> ```

Comment: As the "duplicate" question is not exactly the same, I added an [enhanced answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20733673/1591669) there.