# html5 single datalist definition for many input element

Tags: html, select, datalist

I noticed that in html5 I can write something like:

```
<datalist id="list1">
    <option value="A">
    <option value="B">
</datalist>

input1: <input list="list1">

input2: <input list="list1">
```

That creates two distinct input elements with the same option list.

I'd like to do the same using the classic select element.. I have a web page where I show a list of editable data in rows, and each row has (beside others) a select element. The option list is the same for every select element. If I could define the option list only once, the HTML would be much shorter.
I'm thinking to something like :

```
    <select list="list1">
    </select>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to use JavaScript for this?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to express this in plain html. In this example the option list is static. Consider that in my real case I have a list with about 200 options, and this element could be repeated even 100 times.

Comment: To reduce the lines of html code I could render this element as simple textbox and transform it in a combobox when the user want to edit its value, or load the list with ajax based on the prefix of the text introduced, but I was hoping that what is possible with datalist would be possible with select element, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with HTML5, you’d need (server- or client-side) scripting for this.

The [`select` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-select-element) has no `list` attribute, and neither is there a different mechanism defined that would allow to reference a set of `option` elements.

You could use [`iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) or [`object`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element) elements to [embed a document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20733673/1591669) that contains this `select` element. However, this does not allow you to change the attributes of the `select` element itself, so it’s exactly the same on each occurence. (You can’t have the `iframe`/`object` as child of `select`, so the embedded document needs to have the parent `select` element.)

Comment: Thanks unor, that's what I suspected, too :)